# How can I make my ads appear faster in my android app?

Tags: android, admob, android-sdk-2.1

I've put some ads into one of my android apps and I'm just testing it out on my device.

When I load up my app, it can take around 5-10 seconds for the ad to display. Realistically, the user would have moved onto another screen by then so would never see them.

Is there any way I can have the ad show instantly? If not, how can I ever get ads to display in time for the user to see them (and potentially click)?

I could add some thread delaying on the buttons to stop them doing anything until the ad shows, but that's incredibly dirty...

Comment: Hey, the ad listener has to be linked to an adView right? (`adView.setAdListener`) But I want to check for ads in my adview which is in my main menu. How did you achieve this, as I have the same problem as you, but I don't have an adView in my Splash Screen. Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a splash screen on the application (ImageView over the layout of your main screen), and make it disappear when you receive an add (there's an ad listener on AdMob and most ad providers) or if there's no ad to show. As for the other screens, there's not much you can do other than showing a `ProgressDialog` until the ad shows, but your users won't like it.

Comment: My app only requires internet access for ads, so if they dont have signal then they will forever be stuck on the splash screen.

Comment: then make sure you show the splash only when there is an internet connection. You can also hide the splash image if it's been shown for more than X seconds.

Comment: Hey, the ad listener has to be linked to an adView right? (`adView.setAdListener`) But I want to check for ads in my adview which is in my main menu. How can I do this, do you mind providing an example? Thanks so much!